# How to create an custom Exception/Error Handler class in discord.py which would handle command specific errors?

Tags: python, inheritance, error-handling, discord.py

I'm trying to create a custom error handler in my discord bot. So I have a Cog called MyBot and I'm trying to create an error handler class that would handle the error relating to this class.

I have the below code and it doesn't work.

I expected roll_error() to be called when I hit a BadArguement Error (when I called roll command) but it just raised the error on my console and returned nothing.

```
# BaseErrorHandler.py

from discord.ext import commands

class ErrorHandler(commands.errors.CommandError):

    # Create functions to handle errors globally
    
    pass
```

```
# BotErrorHandler.py 

import ErrorHandler
from discord.ext import commands

class BotErrorHandler(ErrorHandler):

    # Create functions to handle errors related to MyBot

    @commands.command()
    async def roll(self):
        pass

    @roll.error
    async def roll_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, errors.BadArgument):
            await ctx.send('Please enter a valid number')
```

```
# MyBotCog.py
import BotErrorHandler
from discord.ext import commands

class MyBot(commands.Cog, BotErrorHandler):

    def __init__(self, bot, *args, **kwargs):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def roll(self, ctx, low: int, high: int):
        await ctx.send(random.randint(low, high)
```

How can I structure the classes such that this hierarchy works?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Cog.cog_command_error` function to handle all errors from the cog

```py
class SomeCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def foo(self, ctx):
        raise commands.CommandInvokeError("Something went wrong")

    async def cog_command_error(self, ctx, error):
        # Handle the errors from the cog here
        if isinstance(error, commands.CommandInvokeError):
            await ctx.send("Whatever")


bot.add_cog(SomeCog(bot))
```

#### Reference:

- [`Cog.cog_command_error`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Cog.cog_command_error)